# Inside A Kendo TabStrip Template Does Not Work In Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tabstrip

I have two kendo grids. In those grids I have a column which is a checkbox. User can select row or all at once using that column.

It's working fine for one grid which is independent in a page. But another grid is inside a tabstrip. And in that grid, this checkbox column is not working.

Error   CS0412  'item': a parameter or local variable cannot have the same name as a method type parameter.

Error   CS0412  '__razor_template_writer': a parameter or local variable cannot have the same name as a method type parameter.

```js
public class DemoJobs
        {
            public string DemoString { get; set; }
            public int DemoInt { get; set; }
            public decimal DemoDecimal { get; set; }
        }

        public ActionResult GetDemoJobs([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            List<DemoJobs> demoJobs = new List<DemoJobs>();

            DemoJobs d = new DemoJobs();
            d.DemoString = "First";
            d.DemoInt = 1;
            d.DemoDecimal = 1;
            demoJobs.Add(d);

            d = new DemoJobs();
            d.DemoString = "Second";
            d.DemoInt = 2;
            d.DemoDecimal = 2;
            demoJobs.Add(d);

            d = new DemoJobs();
            d.DemoString = "Third";
            d.DemoInt = 3;
            d.DemoDecimal = 3;
            demoJobs.Add(d);

            var jsonObj = Json(demoJobs.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonObj.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

            return jsonObj;
        }
```

```js
function selectedRow(e) {
        var grid = $("#gridDemoJobs").data("kendoGrid");
        var checkboxes = grid.tbody.children().find("[type=checkbox]");

        checkboxes.each(function (i, chkBox) {
            if ($(chkBox).is(":checked")) {
                chkBox.parentElement.parentElement.className = "k-state-selected";
            }            
        })        
    }

    function checkAll(ele) {
        var state = $(ele).is(':checked');
        var grid = $('#gridDemoJobs').data('kendoGrid');
        if (state == true) {
            $('.chkFormols').prop('checked', true);
            selectAllRows(true);
        }
        else {
            $('.chkFormols').prop('checked', false);
            selectAllRows(false);
        }
    };

    function selectAllRows(isSelectAll) {
        var grid = $("#gridDemoJobs").data("kendoGrid");
        var rows = grid.tbody.children();

        rows.each(function (i, row) {
            if (isSelectAll) {
                row.className = "k-state-selected";
            }
        })        
    }
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ServicePROWeb.Controllers.CONTController.DemoJobs>()
                    .Name("gridDemoJobs")
                    .AutoBind(true)
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Template(@<text><input name="chkStatus" type="checkbox" class="chkFormols" /></text>)
                        .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='chkFormols' onClick='selectedRow(this)'/>")
                        .HeaderTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' onClick='checkAll(this)' />").Width(25);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.DemoString).Title("String");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.DemoInt).Title("Int");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.DemoDecimal).Title("Decimal");
                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Batch(true)
                        .ServerOperation(false)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetDemoJobs", "CONT"))
                    )
                )
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                    .Name("demoTabStrip")
                    .Collapsible(false)
                    .Items(tabstrip =>
                    {
                    tabstrip.Add().Text("Demo Job Tab")
                        .Selected(true)
                        .Content(@<div class="jobAllocation">
                            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ServicePROWeb.Controllers.CONTController.DemoJobs>()
                                .Name("gridDemoJobsInside")
                                .AutoBind(true)
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    **@*columns.Template(@<text><input name="chkStatus" type="checkbox" class="chkFormols" /></text>)
                                    .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='chkFormols' onClick='selectedRow(this)'/>")
                                    .HeaderTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' onClick='checkAll(this)' />").Width(25);*@**
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.DemoString).Title("String");
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.DemoInt).Title("Int");
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.DemoDecimal).Title("Decimal");
                                })
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Batch(true)
                                    .ServerOperation(false)
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetDemoJobs", "CONT"))
                                )
                            )
                        </div>);
                    })
                )
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a syntax issue related to nesting inline templates in the Razor code. I have worked around the problem by declaring the Grid as a helper and render it by calling the helper inside the TabStrip template.

```html
@helper  RenderSelectableGrid()
{
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcApp5.Controllers.GridController.DemoJobs>()
                    .Name("gridDemoJobsInside")
                    .AutoBind(true)
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Template(@<text><input name="chkStatus" type="checkbox" class="chkFormols" /></text>)
                            .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='chkFormols' onClick='selectedRow(this)'/>")
                            .HeaderTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' onClick='checkAll(this)' />").Width(25);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.DemoString).Title("String");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.DemoInt).Title("Int");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.DemoDecimal).Title("Decimal");
                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Batch(true)
                        .ServerOperation(false)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetDemoJobs", "Grid"))
                    )
    )
}
```

```html
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("demoTabStrip")
    .Collapsible(false)
    .Items(tabstrip =>
    {
    tabstrip.Add().Text("Demo Job Tab")
        .Selected(true)
        .Content(@<div class="jobAllocation">
            @RenderSelectableGrid()
        </div>);
    })
)
```